# Running a Java program in a Perl/CGI script

Tags: java, perl, apache

I have a program that uses external libraries and code I've written in Java.  However, I want to make it accessible via the web.

If I had full control over the webserver I was running it on, I would probably use Tomcat or JBoss, but I don't have such privileges at my school.

The servers I do have access to have Apache HTTP server with all the normal Linux goodies installed (think: Perl, PHP, etc.)

How would I write a Perl script that runs this Java program?
I've tried the basics such as "system java MyProgram" and "exec java MyProgram", but they don't seem to work.

I'd appreciate any help or insight on this.  Thank you!

Comment: see http://perl.active-venture.com/jpl/docs/Tutorial-callingjava.html

Comment: I looked at that already.  I keep on getting "Can't locate JPL/Class.pm", which is why I abandoned that strategy.  It doesn't mention having to include other libraries or anything like that.

Comment: Does your server have an installed Java VM? I.e., what is the output from `system("java -v")` (or whatever the syntax in your host language is)?

Comment: "java -version" via terminal returns:

java version "1.6.0_18"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.8) (fedora-38.b18.fc12-i386)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 14.0-b16, mixed mode)

Comment: "perl test.pl" via terminal returns the same stuff
Running the script via cgi using a web browser returns -1

Comment: Silly solution.  Is your Java program set up with ant?  If so, can you just `cd $dir; system("ant run");`?  If memory serves that's how I solved this problem in the end when I faced it about 4 years ago.

Answer (score 1):

Process process;

```
    try
    {
      process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd / c start c:\\Perl\\bin\\file.pl");
```

try to run like this as per your program.

Answer (score 0):

When you run a CGI script, the environment is very limited, and this includes the `PATH`. Is it possible that your CGI script can't find the `java` command? Or maybe Perl simply is refusing to run the `system` command when in CGI mode (aka *taint mode*). See [`perldoc perlsec`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsec.html) for more information.

Basically, you need to set PATH and then try running your `system` command with your `java` command.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
system('/full/path/to/java -cp full_class_path my.class.Name');
```